# Accessing a bridged DSL modem from behind a Linksys router

Tags: networking, router, routing, modem

I’ve got a pretty standard home network setup that looks like this, starting from the ISP:

- An ISP-provided DSL modem ([ActionTec PK5001A](http://www.actiontec.com/295.html) if it matters), IP address `192.168.1.1`. I followed [these instructions](http://internethelp.centurylink.com/internethelp/modem-pk5001a-adv-bridging-q.html) to put it in bridge mode.
- A [Linksys WRT54GL](http://www.linksys.com/us/p/P-WRT54GL/) router, IP address `192.168.1.2`. It's connected to the modem through its WAN port and the PC through a LAN port.
- My PC, IP address `192.168.1.95`.

Almost everything is working hunky-dory: I can access the Internet just fine. There is just one piece that’s inconvenient, which is that I can’t access the modem from my PC unless I unplug my PC from the router and plug it directly into the modem.

I’m guessing this is because, being a LAN address, the router tries to route it internally; in particular, the router’s routing table looks like this:

```
Destination       Subnet mask       Gateway           Interface
207.225. 84. 51   255.255.255.255     0.  0.  0.  0   WAN
192.168.  1.  0   255.255.255.  0     0.  0.  0.  0   LAN & Wireless
  0.  0.  0.  0     0.  0.  0.  0   207.225. 84. 51   WAN
```

I thought I might be able to fix this by adding a route for destination `192.168.1.1`, subnet `255.255.255.255` (I only want to change the route for exactly this IP), gateway `0.0.0.0` on the WAN interface. However, when I try to add that route, the router pops up an error message saying only “Invalid static route!.”

Why is this route invalid? How can I access my modem from my PC without shifting my Ethernet cable from the router to the modem?

There is [an existing question](https://superuser.com/questions/841589/accessing-modem-setting-via-router) that seems quite similar; however, it was marked as a duplicate of a question that no longer appears to exist, so there is no longer an answer to that question.

Comment: What is your goal of accessing the modem on an ongoing basis?  Many just directly connect only when they need to change something to troubleshoot.

Comment: Is there some reason you have it set up this way? Why did you connect the modem's LAN port to your router's WAN port? This sounds like "I set up my network so my router considers the modem part of the WAN, but I want the modem to be part of my LAN." Umm, you get what you ask for.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I'd be happy to set up the network differently, if you have a suggestion. Solutions that don't involve buying more hardware are preferable -- I'd rather swap my Ethernet cable occasionally than pay for another device. The key properties of the setup at the moment is that the router need not be a modem; and the modem need not be a wireless access point.

Comment: @DanielWagner Turn off the router's DHCP server (because you only need one on a LAN) and connect the modem to one of the router's LAN ports. Now the modem and router (which is now just an access point and switch) are on the same LAN.

Comment: @JakeGould That's an interesting suggestion! I tried visiting the `207` address I have in my question from the router's routing table, which timed out; I also tried my external IP as suggested by a what's-my-ip service, but that seems to trigger a port forwarding rule I have for serving a personal website from my PC. If I turn off the port forwarding rule, I get the router's admin website instead.

Comment: Let's take a huge step back. This might be an XY problem. Why do you want to access your modem? (Also, your modem is *not* in bridged mode. If it was, it wouldn't have a LAN IP address.)

Comment: @DavidSchwartz "Why do you want to access your modem?" Because problems happen; if possible, I'd like to put in a little bit of effort *now* to reduce the effort of troubleshooting later.

Comment: Ahh, that you are using PPPoE in the router is the missing piece. So your modem is routing, but only the PPPoE traffic. Your best bet is probably to leave things the way they are, I'm afraid. Alternatively, you could number the modem into a different subnet and see if the router will let you access it, possibly with an extra static route.

Answer (score 3):

By far the simplest solution is to move your modem or your LAN to a different subnet.

Eg:

- **Modem:** `192.168.1.1`
- **Router:** `192.168.2.1`

Then it wont have the modem as part of the DHCP pool and will treat it as a remote network (all remote networks go via the same port withe a “router on a stick”).

It’s not uncommon for modems to change over to `192.168.100.1` or similar when bridging for this very reason.

Comment: Great suggestion. I'll accept in the next few days when I have a free time slot to check that I can do it and my wife isn't using the connection.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Is there really double NAT if the modem is in bridge mode? Note in particular that it is the router doing PPPoE, not the modem. The modem is acting *only* as a translation from phone cable to ethernet cable at the moment.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz No, its not a double NAT setup at all. As per title this is a "BRIDGED DSL modem". When bridged your modem is for the most part a dumb device and has no routing features and you dont really need it as part of the local net. Only reason to access it is for DSL diagnostics, which is fine via the above config.

Answer (score 1):

I think, the problem is that you try to create the static route to `192.168.1.1` destination through the port with address `207.225.84.51`.

First you should assign to your WAN port IP-address from the `192.168.1.0` subnet or another address; but then you must also change the modem IP. But you can do this only if your router’s firmware supports PPPoE (or another protocol, used by your ISP) with **Dual Access** (sometimes also called “Russian PPPoE”, “Russian PPTP” etc.). If so, you’d be able to configure router WAN IP separate from the address received by PPPoE connection. Then it would be no problem to create the static route to your modem.

If the official Linksys firmware for this router does not supports **Dual Access** connections, then you can change firmware to **Tomato** or **DD-WRT**, they both supports it.

**Update**. Also you can first try to change LAN IP of your router to IP from another range, e.g. `192.168.10.1`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. The router doesn't seem to support dual access. I might look into one of the alternative firmwares, though as I recall the last time I looked at DD-WRT there was a fairly formidable 30-page "absolutely read this entire thing first or you *will* brick your router" disclaimer. I'm not completely averse to that, but it does make it sort of a backup plan rather than a first choice.